# Regex problem with string ends until a symbol with python

Tags: python

I would like to search with regex and get the same results as `x1` in `x2`

My regex pattern is: `r'firmado por: (.*?)[\-|\n|\.]'`

Thanks

```
import re

class Juez(object):
    def __init__(self, sentencia: str=None):
        super(Juez, self).__init__()
        self.sentencia = sentencia.lower()
        self.unknow_juez = 'unknown'
        self.pattern = r'firmado por: (.*?)[\-|\n|\.]'
    def search_juez(self) -> str:
        juez = re.search(
            pattern=self.pattern,
            string=self.sentencia
        )
        if juez:
            juez = juez.group(1)
            if juez[-1] == ' ':
                juez = juez[:-1]
        else:
            juez = self.unknow_juez
        return juez

sentencia1='Firmado por: Simon Gregorio Laner.'
sentencia2='Firmado por: Simon Gregorio Laner'
x1 = Juez(sentencia=sentencia1).search_juez()
x2 = Juez(sentencia=sentencia2).search_juez()

>>> print(x1)
simon gregorio laner
>>> print(x2)
unknown
```

Comment: Try `r'firmado por: (.*?)\s*\.?$'`

Comment: it works but if I have `sentencia1='Firmado por: Simon Gregorio Laner. Next info'` the pattern don't cut the string @kishkin

Comment: don't work bro! @kishkin

Comment: You need everything up until the first period sign? `r'firmado por: ([^.]+)'`